# How to use Google Charts in an Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google charts in an Ionic app. However, I only get a blank page when testing the app in my browser. what am I doing wrong here?

My app.js file looks like this:

```
angular.module('testGC', ['ionic', 'googlechart', 'googlechart-docs'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    });
    })

.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
    });
```

My index.html file is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <ion-pane>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
                <div google-chart chart1="sampleData" style="width: 100%;height:100%;border: 1px solid green;padding-bottom: 44px" class="has-footer">
                </div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is not getting rendered since:

- `ng-app` directive is missing
- provided data for chart (`$scope.chartObject.data`) contains
  undefined row data (see `$scope.onions`)
- in the declaration of `chart` div element, invalid directive `chart1`
  is specified and undefined `sampleData` is bound

**Modified `index.html`**

```
<body ng-app="chartApp">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
            <div google-chart chart="chartObject" class="chart-container">
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

**Modified `app.js`**

```
angular.module('chartApp', ['ionic', 'googlechart'])

.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";

    $scope.chartObject.data = {
        "cols": [
            { id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string" },
            { id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number" }
        ], "rows": [
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Mushrooms" },
                   { v: 3 },
                ]
            },
            //{ c: $scope.onions },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Olives" },
                   { v: 31 }
                ]
            },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Zucchini" },
                   { v: 1 },
                ]
            },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Pepperoni" },
                   { v: 2 },
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
});
```

**[Demo:Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j4weQQUMPiOZWPzLa95p?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Your template points to an object named `sampleData`, but the code is creating an object named `chartObject`. You also have `chart1=`, which should be `chart=`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed this, but it still shows only the blank starter page without a chart. When I look in the Chrome Javascript Console it says: Failed to load http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).  Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  But the first thing I would do is start sticking messages with console.log() everywhere to see if the code is actually running.  I would also inspect the page elements to see if angular is rendering the page.

Comment: Actually, Now that I look, I don't see an ng-app directive in your file anywhere.  You need something like ng-app="testGC", usually on the HTML or body element.  Without it, angular won't process the page.